# USPS Shipping Label

Tags: php, usps

I'm working with the USPS Shipping Label API. I'm getting a great response from the API for my request. The method name is `ExpressMailIntl`.

The `labelimage` field with values is returning from the API as encrypted format.

How to convert the encrypted string to an image?

Comment: Are you sure its encrypted and not base 64 encoded? What does the API documentation tell you?

Comment: Which one of the many APIs are you using *exactly*? https://www.usps.com/business/webtools.htm Can you provide the exact name and reference?

Comment: This is the API reference. https://www.usps.com/webtools/htm/International-Labels-v4-4.htm

Answer (score 2):

According to [Delivery Confirmation - USPS Web Tools™ Application Programming Interface - User’s Guide - Document Version 8.1c (01/22/2012)](https://www.usps.com/webtools/htm/Delivery-Confirmation-v8-1c.htm):

> The image returned is Base64-encoded in PDF or TIF format, according to your request (`<ImageType>`).  It must be decoded before use.  For additional information on Base64-encoding and decoding, consult the following working group web sites: [Network Working Group Section 4.3.2.4](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1421.txt?number=1421) and N[etwork Working Group Section 6.8](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt?number=2045).

There is nothing told about encryption just about base64 encoding.

See [`base64_decode`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/base64_decode) for a PHP function that can decode base64 into common octect binary.

Answer (score 1):

You can save this as pdf. USPS sends pdf format label.

```
 $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);

 $label_img = $xml->DeliveryConfirmationLabel;

 $label_title = 'label.pdf';

 $file=fopen($label_title,"w");

 fwrite($file,base64_decode($label_img));
```